# Prove that the estimator is unbiased, Scaled t-distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, proof-explanation, density-function, parameter-estimation

$X$ is a random variable with a scaled t distribution with $d=5$.
Density: $$f(x)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d+1}{2})}{\theta\sqrt{d\pi}\Gamma(d/2)} ( 1+\frac{x^2}{d\theta ^2})^{-\frac{d+1}{2}}$$

How do I prove that the unbiased estimate of $\theta^2$ is given by
$$\hat{\theta^2}=\frac{3}{500}\sum^{100}_{i=1}x^2_i,$$
where we have a sample size of 100 generated data points when $\theta=2$.
How do I Use this formula to estimate $\theta$? I assume taking the square root?

I need to prove the estimator is unbiased, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square of a T-distributed random variable is an F-distributed random variable, which has known mean.  This should allow you to find the expected value of your estimator.

Since you have $X \sim \theta \cdot \text{T}(df = 5)$ you therefore have $X^2 \sim \theta^2 \cdot \text{F}(df_1 = 1, df_2 = 5)$ which means that $\mathbb{E} (X^2)= \tfrac{5}{3} \theta^2$.  This gives you:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} (\hat{\theta}^2) 
= \mathbb{E} \Bigg( \frac{3}{500} \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i^2 \Bigg) 
&= \frac{3}{500} \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathbb{E}(X_i^2) \\[8pt]
&= \frac{3}{500} \sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{5}{3} \cdot \theta^2 \\[8pt]
&= \frac{3}{500} \cdot \frac{500}{3} \cdot  \theta^2 \\[8pt]
&= \theta^2.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This shows the estimator $\hat{\theta}^2$ to be unbiased for $\theta^2$.